# Finding the second-to last node in a singly linked list

Tags: java, list, singly-linked-list

So I have an implementation of the Singly Linked List and I am trying to add a method which reports the second to last node of the list. However, I was not sure if I am allowed to write the method under the Node class then access it from the Singly Linked List class. If I do this, my instance variable of the node class('head' is used as a variable to access the penultimate method but also as the input of the penultimate method. Is that okay? Below is my implementation/attempt.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList { 

    private static class Node<Integer>{
        private Integer element;
        private Node<Integer> next;
        private Node<Integer> penultimate;

        public Node(Integer e, Node<Integer> n) {
            element = e;
            next = n;
            penultimate = null;
        }
        public Integer getElement() {return element;}
        public Node<Integer> getNext(){return next;}
        public void setNext(Node<Integer> n) {next = n;}
        public Node<Integer> penultimate(Node<Integer> head) {
            Node<Integer> current = head;
            while(current != null) {
                if(head.getNext() == null) {
                    penultimate = head;
                }
                else {
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            }
            return penultimate;
        }
    }

    private Node<Integer> head = null;
    private Node<Integer> tail = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {}

        public int size() {
            return size;
        }
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return size == 0;
        }
        public Integer first() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return head.getElement();
        }
        public Integer last() {
            if(isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return tail.getElement();
        }
        public void addFirst(Integer i) {
            head = new Node<> (i, head);
            if(size == 0) {
                tail = head;
            }
            size++;
        }
        public void addLast(Integer i) {
            Node<Integer> newest = new Node<>(i,null);
            if(isEmpty()) {
                head = newest;
            }
            else {
                tail.setNext(newest);
            tail = newest;
            size++;
            }
        }
        public Integer removeFirst() {
            if(isEmpty()) {
                return null;
                }
            Integer answer = head.getElement();
            head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            if(size == 0) {
                tail = null;
            }
            return answer;
        }
        public void getPenultimate() {

            if(isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("List is empty. Please check.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The second last node is: " + head.penultimate(head));
            }

        }
```

Comment: I believe that `penultimate` should not be implemented in `Node` class. Because this is to come from hole list not from a single node. So ideally it should be in `SinglyLinkedList ` class

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the field `penultimate`. You do not want it in every node, in fact in no node, but calculated.

In the Node's penultimate method `head` should not be used in the loop.

```
//private Node<Integer> penultimate;

// head: ...#->#->#->P->null
public Node<Integer> penultimate(Node<Integer> head) {
    Node<Integer> penultimate = null;
    Node<Integer> current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getNext() == null) {
            penultimate = current;
            break;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return penultimate;
}
```

Or the third (second?) to last node:

```
// head: ...#->#->#->P->#->null
public Node<Integer> penultimate(Node<Integer> head) {
    Node<Integer> penultimate = null;
    Node<Integer> current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getNext() == null) {
            break;
        }
        penultimate = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return penultimate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a follow-up question. Is it okay to have penultimate method in the node class? I was wondering if it will still iterate over the whole list?

Comment: In general it would be okay, but not a **public** method, it is an internal method needing the list's `head`.

Comment: So: one public method in the list, but it may call a method in the node class.

Comment: So you mean that I should declare a public method in the SinglyLinkedList class (getPenultimate method) then call a private method from the Node class (in this case, penultimate method)? Thanks so much for your time, btw!

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep track of the second to last node?

```
private Node<Integer> head = null;
private Node<Integer> tail = null;
private Node<Integer> secondToLast = null;
private int size = 0;

public SinglyLinkedList() {}

public int size() {
    return size;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
public Integer first() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return head.getElement();
}
public Integer last() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return tail.getElement();
}
public void addFirst(Integer i) {
    if (size == 1) {
        secondToLast = head;
    }
    head = new Node<> (i, head);
    if(size == 0) {
        tail = head;
    }
    size++;
}
public void addLast(Integer i) {
    Node<Integer> newest = new Node<>(i,null);
    if(isEmpty()) {
        head = newest;
    }
    else {
        tail.setNext(newest);
        secondToLast = tail;
    }
    tail = newest;
    size++;

}
public Integer removeFirst() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
        }
    Integer answer = head.getElement();
    head = head.getNext();
    size--;
    if(size == 0) {
        tail = null;
    }
    if (size == 1) {
        secondToLast = null;
    }
    return answer;
}
public void getPenultimate() {

    if(isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("List is empty. Please check.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The second last node is: " + secondToLast);
    }

}
```